# How to create a column with auto increment and condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a DDDD column that auto increment and group by key and tag_en column. If the value on tag_en is the same, so does the DDDD value

I have tried pandas with group by and cumcount

```py
df1['DDDD'] = df1.groupby(['key']).cumcount()+1
```

Here is the link of the image how I want the data to be and what I got
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu9I0.jpg

Edit: Sorry this is my bad I just figure it out that each time a new key appear I need to reset the DDDD value start from zero https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYF3D.jpg

Comment: Use `df1['DDDD'] = df1.groupby(['key','tag_en']).ngroup()`

Comment: Edit: Sorry this is my bad I just figure it out that each time a new key appear I need to reset the DDDD value start from 1 https://imgur.com/MEnDOO7

Comment: Then use `df1['DDDD'] = df1.groupby('key').ngroup()`

Comment: Can I somehow change the DDDD column in order to start from 0001 instead of 0000

Comment: I am afraid that if do not put tag_en in group by the value of DDDD column will be all the same https://imgur.com/j0EsBtX

Comment: Yes, it is expected, because same values in `key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html), add `1`, convert to strings by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last add zeros with [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key':['name','name','name','age','age','age','weight','weight','weight'], 
                    'tag_en':['me','me','notme',18,18,18,100,101,102],
                    'CCC':['001','001','001','002','002','002','003','003','003'],
                    'DDDD':['0001','0001','0002','0001','0001','0001','0001','0002','0003']})


df1['DDDD1'] = (df1.groupby('key', sort=False)['tag_en']
                  .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
                  .add(1)
                  .astype(str)
                  .str.zfill(4))
print (df1)            
      key tag_en  CCC  DDDD DDDD1
0    name     me  001  0001  0001
1    name     me  001  0001  0001
2    name  notme  001  0002  0002
3     age     18  002  0001  0001
4     age     18  002  0001  0001
5     age     18  002  0001  0001
6  weight    100  003  0001  0001
7  weight    101  003  0002  0002
8  weight    102  003  0003  0003
```

Comment: The DDDD value some how jump from 002 to 0236 https://imgur.com/LrCW0Cc

Comment: I think this is the final form I want it to be, anyway thank you for your dedication https://imgur.com/Q6wQ7UZ

Comment: This is the sample data df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key':['name','name','name','age','age','age','weight','weight','weight'], 'tag_en':['me','me','notme',18,18,18,100,101,102],'CCC':[001,001,001,002,002,002,003,003,003]}) and the result {'DDDD':[0001,0001,0002,0001,0001,0001,0001,0002,0003]}

Comment: For each group of key if tag_en is the same so does the dddd value, otherwise it will auto increment until reach the next key group. If it is reach the next key group the dddd start from 1 thats how it works CCC just like the key. The last is 1,2,3 because it's tag_en is different from each other so the dddd will move on

Comment: I think your DDDD is incorrect. Mine is {'DDDD':[0001,0001,0002,0001,0001,0001,0001,0002,0003]} the reason why DDDD in 'weight' is 1,2,3 because 'tag_en' is different from each other so the DDDD just auto increment . If 'tag_en' in 'weight' is [100,100,100] then DDDD is [1,1,1] , if [100,100,101] then [1,1,2]

Comment: @Kai - oops, I create bad data sample. Now understand and answer is edited.

Comment: You made my day man, really appreciate that. Working perfectly